# JPA manytomany keep list order while using @JoinTable

Tags: java, jpa, many-to-many, sql-order-by

I am using a class to hold a list of persisted objects, and the order of those objects really matter to me.

The class looks like this:

```
public class Class implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -8772078256979276783L;

@ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.REFRESH})
@JoinTable(name = "join_table",
        joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name="joinColumn") 
},
inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name="inverseJoinColumn")
}
)
private List<AbstractVariant> variablesList;
}
```

Is there a way to add to that JoinTable an index to specify the position on the list, therefore,keeping the order safe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's the goal of the [`@OrderColumn`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OrderColumn.html) annotation.

Comment: You are right, I thought that I had to use a different annotation inside the JoinTable annotation instead of using the ordercolumn one. Using the OrderColumn fixed it.